# how to use IATA-3 letter code in Sabre instaFlights Search API?

Tags: php, get, request, sabre

I am using instaFlights Search API of Sabre. I am unable to get response for any of the IATA 3-letter codes other then "JFK" and "LAX". Whenever I pass any other IATA code in the request like "DXB", i recieve an error.
please note that I am working on test environment and testing the api on the link given below.

[link of API test page](https://developer.sabre.com/io-docs)

The error that i receive every time i request with any other IATA Code.

[image: error snapshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you in CERT or PROD?

If you are still in CERT, only a subset of available flight schedules/fares will be found and returned. Do you have access to PROD? If you're working in PROD and not getting any results then I would think something else is malformed in your request.

Comment: I am in certification, probably that is why it is happening. Thanks BTW.

Answer (score 0):

InstaFlight is limited to specific POS (Point of Sale) and the available city pairs are tied to the POS being used.

I recommed you to contact the API Support team for further details.